# Sending an email via domain email using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Here I want to send an email from my own domain email(i.e. info@mydomain.com not using gmail/outlook) address. My question is here "What configuration should I setup?

```
//EMAIL CONFIGUARATION 
$config['email']['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['email']['smtp_host'] = '??????????????????';
$config['email']['smtp_user'] = 'info@mydomain.com';
$config['email']['smtp_pass'] = '********';
$config['email']['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['email']['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['email']['charset']   = 'utf-8';
$config['email']['wordwrap']  = TRUE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to ask your hosting provider for your SMTP server.

Comment: Okey thanks ... Will my smtp url look like this ssl://smtp.mydomain.com as google's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your own SMTP server? You need one and you will need to configure code igniter to use those settings. If you do not have an smtp server, you will need to buy one or check if your server or hosting provider has some for you to use.